# Stream list of numbers from SQL Server as single byte array

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm looking for the fastest way to get a list of longs from SQL Server.

As far as I know the code below is the fastest you can normally go, and what slows it down is all the stuff that happens in dr.Read() and to some extent the invokation of dr.GetInt64 for each row.

```
var ids = new long[count];
using (var dr = new SqlCommand(string.Format(@"SELECT TOP 10000 ID FROM Data", count),
    conn).ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))    
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        ids[i++] = dr.GetInt64(0);                        
    }
}
```

The time the query takes is negligible, thus the time is spend with parsing and type validation in the data reader. For 100,000 records it takes ~25 ms which is extremely slow compared to the 0.20 ms it takes to iterate 100,000 items in an array.

Since I'm only asking for a list of longs I'm wondering if it is possible to get those as a single byte array. What I'm after is something like:

```
var bytes = (byte[]) new SqlCommand("(I don't know)", conn).ExecuteScalar();                
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, ids, 0, 10000);
```

That would reduce the parsing time considerably.

Can someone please tell me if this approach is possible?

***UPDATE:***

At least these approaches are not faster:

**CLR Aggregate**

It's possible to define custom aggregate functions written in .NET. I tried to make a very simple one that does nothing (with SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.Native) for it to be as fast as possible). That increased query time to 60 ms so it can never be faster.

The query goes like:

```
SELECT dbo.ByteIt(ID) FROM (SELECT TOP 100000 ID FROM Data) T
```

**Concatenation of varbinary(max)**

It's possible to build the byte array with pure SQL. That is very slow.

```
DECLARE @n varbinary(max)
SET @n = 0;
SELECT TOP 10000 @n = @n + cast(id as varbinary(8)) FROM Data;
SELECT @n;
```

**Why it will probably never be worth the effort**

The fastest native aggregate I can think of is COUNT.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM (SELECT TOP 100000 ID FROM Data) T
```

That takes 10 ms and must be the absolute lower bound for any method that considers each value. I don't find that performance gain worth the effort.

Sadly, I think the answer to my question is "It can be done but not faster. Live with the 25 ms".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are selecting values now is really optimal; the [Tabular Data Stream protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream) is optimized for transferring results from SQL Server back to a clien.  Your best approach is to use the client tools you have now (`SqlConnection‘ et al).

Here are two alternate approaches, but I don't recommend them and I'll explain why.

As always, YMMV and you should test, test, test.

You would call the [`GetBytes` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx) on the [`SqlDataReader` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9ttex) to read the bytes sequentially and convert them into [`Int64` instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) (probably through the [`BitConverter.ToInt64` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64.aspx)).

Note, in order to do this, you'd have to pass [`CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx) to the [call to `Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx) on the [`SqlCommand` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4956bkc) so that the large binary value is streamed from the server.

That said, you'd now have to construct the large binary array to pass back in a field.  This is where this approach gets hung up on, IMO.  Basically, you would have to do a pivot (not a literal pivot, but something similar) taking the set of `bigint` values and creating a large binary value from it.  This is not inherently a set operation, and you're probably going to have to have some loop code in your sproc to create this value.

With that in mind, it would seem that any gain that you get from streaming a large binary value to the client is going to be negated (and possibly made worse) by the CPU cycles that you're going to spin trying to construct that large binary value from the list of `bigint`.

You *might* be able to mitigate some of that by having a [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) which will take the list of `bigint` and then create the byte array for you, but at that point, it might be overkill.

The CLR stored procedure would be faster at performing procedural operations (which this is, it's not set-based, which T-SQL is better suited for).  The number of reads would initially be the same (after all, you'll have to get the data to create the binary string with) but your probably run up memory (dependent on the size of your set, since you have to concatenate it into one value) as well as CPU (due to the concatenation) before you even send your first byte back to the client, all of which takes time.

Comment: I just did some testing with a custom CLR aggregate which must be the fastest way to throw .NET after values in SQL Server. (SELECT dbo.ByteIt(ID) FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 ID FROM DATA) T). Even when it does nothing, the query time is 60 ms which is more than double the time for retrieving the rows. So you're right that CLR is not the way to go.

Comment: @niels I've updated the answer to address more about why you want to use the default as well as why you'd want to not use CLR stored procedures.  Hopefully it comes off less as "things you could try which don't work" and more "what you're doing is optimal and here are examples of what you could but won't work and why."

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using SQL Server, you could do this:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + ID
                     FROM Data
                     FOR XML PATH('') 
                     ), 1, 1, '')
```

You'll get a comma-separated list of the IDs. This is based on stuff I learned from this article - http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/.

Please note that I haven't run any timing tests on this approach. I like it because it's fairly simple.